# WebMethod call from JavaScript fails.

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, web-services, webmethod

I have following class

```
namespace UI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Registration1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "UI")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Registration1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static string RegisterUser(string sFirstName)
        {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

and in the client I added my JavaScript,

```
UI.Registration.RegisterUser(txtFirstName.get_value(),Register_success, onFailed);
```

And in Script Manger

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" Runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Registration.asmx" />
    </Services>
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

But still, when I run it, it doesn't see the UI namespace, and I get a JavaScript runtime error.

Comment: btw I implemented the Register_success, onFailed methods

Answer (score 2):

Your class is named Registration1, but you're calling a method on a class named Registration.